# How to get ID from a string "REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 1]"

Tags: ruby

Hello i have a list of strings

```
"REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 1]"
"REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 2434]"
"REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 324]"
```

How do i get the id from each string so the output is like this?

```
"REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 1]"
=> 1
"REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 2434]"
=> 2434
"REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 324]"
=> 324
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
"REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 1]".scan(/id: (\d+)/).flatten[0].to_i
=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If Title never starts with an integer, I see a much simpler pattern:

```
str = "REF Product: [Title: gr8vh1, id: 2434]"
str[/ \d+/].strip #regex to find integer after whitespace
#=> "2434"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Hash` from this string:

```
h = Hash[s[/\[(.*)\]/, 1].split(", ").map(&:split)]
# => {"Title:"=>"gr8vh1", "id:"=>"1"}

puts h["id:"]
# => "1"
```